# Novatec QR D812SB max speed?

Tags: freehub

Can anybody tell the specification of Novatec QR D812SB? I'm looking to buy used wheelset using these hub. Can I use Shimano 11 Speed using this?

I am looking at this https://issuu.com/novatecwheels/docs/novatec_hubs_guide_2014 but not sure how to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on other experience it should be able handle 11 Speed.

But because it's already discontinued, I've been able to negotiate to buy only the rim(WTB Frequency Team i23).